Next.js 14 how to use proxy with fetch
Nextjs project running in PVM with Node.js version 18.18.2. Migrated from next.js 12 to 14.2.4 and in order to use Next.js new features i replaced axios with fetch. The issue is that all outgoing server side requests have to go through a proxy which is easy to do with axios but i can't find how to do it with fetch.
axios.get('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
    {
        proxy: {
            protocol: 'http',
            host: '149.129.239.170',
            port: 8080
        }
    }
)

The only proxy related thing i found in the docs is rewrites but this is irrelevant in my case. I know i can still use axios with unstable_cache and cache but it is much cleaner to just use native fetch so i would like to achieve this somehow (also after a lot of testing although unstable_cache and cache helps with deduping and caching seems like in some cases using fetch results in even less calls and much cleaner code).

Since this is an HTTPS request through a proxy, consider this answer.

In Node.js, libraries like axios or node-fetch have supported configuring proxies using an agent option. However, with the introduction of the native fetch API in Node.js 18, you might expect to be able to configure proxies similarly.
Unfortunately, the native fetch API in Node.js does not support the agent option. This design choice is intentional, aligning the Node.js fetch implementation with the browser’s fetch API, which also does not support custom agents. The reasoning behind this decision is discussed in detail in this GitHub issue.
You can also see this related Stack Overflow discussion: Why is the agent option not available in Node native fetch?.
